# foreach on json data

Tags: json, rest, codeigniter

Hi i want to insert values into table which is posted from api
json data is

```
{"questions":{"34":"Yes", "46":"good", "48":"NA", "29":"Yes", "45":"ravi", "49":"Negative", "43":"1 BHK", "35":"Neighbour", "38":"14", "39":"9", "27":"1", 
"41":"Married", "52":"vijay@123.com", "47":"good", "31":"Bunglow", "33":"Middle Class", "37":"Owned By Parents", "30":"good", "50":"easy", 
"51":"comments", "32":"No", "44":"[MusicSystem,PC,Refrigerator,Airconditioner]"}}
```

when i convert into array it is

```
Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [34] => Yes
            [46] => good
            [48] => NA
            [29] => Yes
            [45] => ravi
            [49] => Negative
            [43] => 1 BHK
            [35] => Neighbour
            [38] => 14
            [39] => 9
            [27] => 1
            [41] => Married
            [52] => ravi@gmail.com
            [47] => good
            [31] => Bunglow
            [33] => Middle Class
            [37] => Owned By Parents
            [30] => good
            [50] => easy
            [51] => comments
            [32] => No
            [44] => [MusicSystem,PC,Refrigerator,Airconditioner]
        )

)
```

how to get this values like

using foreach
$question=34;
$answer= yes;

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.Convert json into array using `json_decode()`.And make a new array with key and value.Then just print the first key and value.

```
<?php
$json = '{"questions":{"34":"Yes", "46":"good", "48":"NA", "29":"Yes", "45":"ravi", "49":"Negative", "43":"1 BHK", "35":"Neighbour", "38":"14", "39":"9", "27":"1", 
"41":"Married", "52":"vijay@123.com", "47":"good", "31":"Bunglow", "33":"Middle Class", "37":"Owned By Parents", "30":"good", "50":"easy", 
"51":"comments", "32":"No", "44":"[MusicSystem,PC,Refrigerator,Airconditioner]"}}
';
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//print_r($array);
foreach($array['questions'] as $key=>$value)
{
    $arr[] = array('key'=>$key,'value'=>$value);
}
//print_r($arr);
echo "Question:".$arr[0]['key'].PHP_EOL;
echo "Answer:".$arr[0]['value'];
```

Output:

```
Question:34
Answer:Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a single value while having the key, you can do `$array["questions"][34]` to get the answer `yes`.
If you want to loop through all of them, you can do this loop:

```
foreach($array["questions"] as $no => $ans){
    echo "Question: $no";
    echo "Answer: $ans";
}
```